# Linq Query reuse

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a Linq Query, Which Returns alot of results From SQL Server, I want to make sure, I get the records from database ONCE and then simply loop through the records on demand within the page without hitting DB.

Here is a Simple Query:

```
Dim c1 = (From c2 In _db.CategoryRelationShip
        Select c2)
```

Now Somewhere in Page I do:

```
For Each item In c1

Next
```

And Then Again:

```
For Each item In c1

Next
```

Does this mean in every For Loop, I am hitting database again and again? or my orignal Linq retieved all the records and i am simply looping through the array/results?

I heard about toList() method, so i am confused do i need it or not?... i mean what if I do:

```
Dim c1 = (From c2 In _db.CategoryRelationShip
        Select c2).toList()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ uses deferred execution, which means that nothing gets evaluated until you need the data. This statement:

```
Dim c1 = (From c2 In _db.CategoryRelationShip
          Select c2)
```

does not fetch any data from the database. As Gert Arnold put it in the comments to the other answer:

> `c1` is just a query waiting to happen (deferred execution).

So yes. You will execute the query twice if you just iterate over `c1`. You can easily verify this:

```
Dim myCollection As New List(Of Integer)(New () {1, 2})

Dim result = (From c In myCollection
              Select c)

For Each i As Integer In result
    Console.WriteLine(i)    ' Will print 1 and 2
Next

myCollection.Add(3)
Console.WriteLine()

For Each i As Integer In result
    Console.WriteLine(i)    ' Will print 1, 2 and 3
Next
```

You can do the same test with your database.

To avoid calling the DB twice you can use `.ToList()` which will "force" the query to be evaluated and the result stored in a list. If you were to replace `(From c In myCollection Select c)` with `(From c In myCollectionc Select c).ToList()` in the above example, you would print 1 and 2 twice.

Comment: nice, what a difference...my page is running much faster....so what if I call ".Take(10)" OR ".SingleorDefault" or ".Count"....would they execute query right away?

Comment: @highwingers The best way to figure out what happens is to try it. `SingleOrDefault` and `Count` would execute right away, while `Take` would not. If a method returns a single value, it will most likely not use deferred execution.